# Javascript positive lookbehind alternative

Tags: javascript, regex

So, js apparantly doesn't support lookbehind.

What I want is a regex valid in javascript that could mimic that behavior.

Specifically, I have a string that consists of numbers and hyphens to denote a range. As in,

```
12 - 23
12 - -23
-12 - 23
-12 - -23
```

Please ignore the spaces. These are the only cases possible, with different numbers, of course.
What I want is to match the first hyphen that separates the numbers and is not a minus sign. In other words, the first hyphen followed by a digit. But the digit shouldn't be part of the match.

So my strings are:

```
12-23
12--23
-12-23
-12--23
```

And the match should be the 3rd character in the 1st 2 cases and the 4th character in the last two.

The single regex I need is expected to match the character in brackets.

```
12(-)23
12(-)-23
-12(-)23
-12(-)-23
```

This can be achieved using positive lookbehind :

```
(?<=[0-9])\-
```

But javascript doesn't support that. I want a regex that essentially does the same thing and is valid in js.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What you have tried ? please add you code

Comment: Why it isn't consider as hyphen in the third case?

Comment: your question is not at all clear `3rd character in the 1st 2 cases` means `2`  and `4th character in the last two.` means `-` and `-` what does that mean

Comment: Second and fourth case are same.Why difference in expected output

Comment: @Tushar Are trying to parse this expression? May I suggest you to try instead `range.indexOf('-', 1)` to locate the index of the separating hyphen? BTW, I see nothing wrong with the question you've asked.

Comment: @incarnate: thanks. For your solution, it won't work because the 1st number can be negative or positive, so the hyphen for range can be the 1st or 2nd occurance of the string.

Comment: @vks 2nd case has (+)12 has 1st term, 4th case has -12

Comment: @aelor - I'm trying to match the FIRST hyphen FOLLOWED by a digit. That's why i gave character indices starting at 1.

Comment: @Tushar - there's some misunderstanding as to what your required results are. Posting the characters you like in the match for your given inputs would resolve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you want to match the delimiting hyphen, instead of just matching the whole string and capture the numbers:

```
input.match(/(-?\d+) *- *(-?\d+)/)
```

The 2 numbers will be in capturing group 1 and 2.

It is possible to write a regex which works for **sanitized input** (no space, and guaranteed to be valid as shown in the question) by using `\b` to check that `-` is preceded by a word character:

```
\b-
```

Since the only word characters in the sanitized string is `0-9`, we are effectively checking that `-` is preceded by a digit.

Comment: I was wondering about that too, why would you want to match the hyphen?

Comment: @nhahtdh. THanks for answering. Is there any way i can refer to the groups outside the regex in js? Say in the next line of code, could you show me how to save the captured number in a variable?

Comment: To answer you question, this is part of a bigger code with real time validation and more datatypes than numbers. Long story short, matching the hyphen would make my life easier.

Comment: @Tushar: I can write a regex that can work for the cases in the question, but fails miserably on wild input. For example, `\b-` would work for the cases without spaces, but won't for cases with space.

Comment: @nhahtdh - DUDE, you did it. THANKS A MILL. I've already sanitized my user input to remove spaces and junk values. Your regex works for my purposes.

Comment: I still can't get my head around about what your purpose is but good you got it solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d+.*?)(?:\s+(-)\s+)(.*?\d+)
```

You probably want this though i dont know why there is a diff between expected output of `2nd` and `4th`.Probably its a typo.You can try this replace by `$1$2$3`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/26

```
var re = /(\d+.*?)(?:\s+(-)\s+)(.*?\d+)/gmi;
var str = '12 - 23\n12 - -23\n-12 - 23\n-12 - -23';
var subst = '$1$2$3';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```