# js regex - get string between expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to match string in javascript, but take only part from matched string.

E.g i have string 'my test string' and use match function to get only 'test':

```
var text = 'my test string';
var matched = text.match(/(?=my).+(?=string)/g);
```

iam tried to get it in this way but it will return 'my test'.
How can i do this to get only 'test' with regex?

Comment: Use capturing group #1 as `/my (.+?)(?= string)/`

Comment: Relevant: [what is the difference between ?:, ?! and ?= in regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804732/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-regex) and [Javascript positive lookbehind alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265515/javascript-positive-lookbehind-alternative). Your first group is a lookahead, not a lookbehind. JS doesn't support lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [capture group:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-capturing-parentheses)

```
var match = text.match(/my (.*) string/g);
# match[0] will be the whole string, match[1] the capture group
match[1];
```

this will still match the whole string, but you can get the contents with `match[1]`.

Some other regex engines have a feature called "lookbehind", but this is unsupported in JavaScript, so I recommend the method with the capture group.

Comment: `match` will be: `["my test string"]`. The `string.match` function returns only $0 group (as many times as it matched)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your regex to `/my (.+) string/g` and create RegExp object from it:

```
var regex = new RegExp(/my (.+) string/g);
```

Then use `regex.exec(string)` to get the **capturing groups**:

```
var matches = regex.exec(text);
```

`matches` will be an array with the value: `["my test string", "test"]`.

`matches` contains 2 groups: `$0` and `$1`. `$0` is the whole match, and `$1` is the first capturing group. `$1` it's what inside the parentheses: `.+`.

You need `$1`, so you can get it by writing `matches[1]`:

```
//This will return the string you want
var matched = matches[1];
```